# How to fill in missing months?

Tags: sqlite

I've got the following SQL:

```
  SELECT STRFTIME('%m', date) ord,
         CASE STRFTIME('%m', date) WHEN '01' THEN 'January' 
                                   WHEN '02' THEN 'Febuary'
                                   WHEN '03' THEN 'March' 
                                   WHEN '04' THEN 'April' 
                                   WHEN '05' THEN 'May' 
                                   WHEN '06' THEN 'June' 
                                   WHEN '07' THEN 'July' 
                                   WHEN '08' THEN 'August' 
                                   WHEN '09' THEN 'September' 
                                   WHEN '10' THEN 'October' 
                                   WHEN '11' THEN 'November' 
                                   WHEN '12' THEN 'December' 
         ELSE '' END AS month,
         count(*) AS count 
    FROM events 
   WHERE type='Birth' AND 
         date <> '' 
GROUP BY month,ord
ORDER BY ord
```

This gives me results similar to:

```
ord  month        count
01   January      1
02   Febuary      1
03   March        3
05   May          4
07   July         2
08   August       2
09   September    2
11   November     4
```

But as you can see it has gaps. Is there any way to fill in the missing months with a 0 count?

Comment: Try using this as example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17916567/342740

Comment: This is how similar problem solved in TSQL: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/08/29/tsql-filling-missing-date-range/ Not sure about capabilities of SQLite, but I think similar logic could be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Study outer join.

Run the following once:

```
CREATE TABLE months (
  mm char(2),
  name char(10)
);
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('01', 'January');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('02', 'Febuary');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('03', 'March');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('04', 'April');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('05', 'May');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('06', 'June');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('07', 'July');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('08', 'August');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('09', 'September');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('10', 'October');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('11', 'November');
INSERT INTO months VALUES ('12', 'December');
```

And run this:

```
  SELECT m.mm AS ord,
         m.name AS month,
         count(e.date) AS count
    FROM months m LEFT OUTER JOIN events e
      ON strftime('%m', e.date) = m.mm
   WHERE e.type='Birth' AND 
         e.date <> '' 
GROUP BY month,ord
ORDER BY ord;
```