# Populate PHP sales table from MySQL (inc. empty months)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query, which returns sales by month:

```
SELECT YEAR(txn_date) as 'year', MONTHNAME(txn_date) as 'month',
SUM(grand_total) as 'sales'
FROM transactions
WHERE YEAR(txn_date) BETWEEN '$last_year' AND '$this_year'
GROUP BY month
```

What's a good way of populating a table showing sales for the last two years, by month, including months that have no sales? Normally I like to get SQL to do as much as possible, but in this case I don't think it can help me as there's no month table or anything like that.

Am I going to have to do some crude For Loop that counts to 12 and searches through the array for matches on month and year? I feel I'm missing some obvious, elegant way of doing this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916322/mysql-to-select-month-wise-record-even-if-data-not-exist

Comment: @JayBlanchard Given the PHP tag, and specific mention above, I disagree that this is a duplicate of *that* question (but that's not to say it isn't a duplicate of some other question)

Comment: I kind of agree @Strawberry, but since there is no PHP in the question I would consider this a tough call.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well, there's a dollar ($).

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ @Strawberry I *always* let the database do the heavy lifting, especially since it is designed for just such a thing.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know we're talking small data sets here, but left joining missing data is slow. Besides, it just seems antithetical to me. Databases are for the storage and retrieval of data, not data presentation, and not the fabrication of data that isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily build in-line tables for months / years using `CROSS JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT y.`year` AS 'year',  x.`month` AS 'month', SUM(grand_total) AS 'sales'
FROM (
   SELECT 1 AS `month` UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12 ) AS x
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT 2015 AS ` year` UNION ALL SELECT 2016) AS y
LEFT JOIN transactions AS z ON x.`month` =  MONTH(txn_date) AND
                               y.`year` = YEAR(txn_date)
GROUP BY x.`month`, y.`year`
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4e04/5)

Comment: Hmm, I get 12 results with NULL in every column.

Comment: @daninthemix Can you set up a sqlfiddle mockup demonstrating the issue?

Comment: [How about a screenshot?](http://abload.de/img/db1fbkbk.png) By the way, my sample data at the moment only has dates from within the last two months. I'd also be happy for a query that spits out all twelve months (whether or not there's any transactions) for a particular year. And then I'll just run the query once for each year I need it.

Comment: Given the scope of the question, this is a bad way. For a good way, see PHP loops.

Comment: @Strawberry I personally disagree. It is far better getting the exact result you need right from the DBMS. Building up a numbers table like the way is done in my query is pretty efficient as well.

Comment: @daninthemix Please check the edits I've made. It should work now.

Comment: It's wasted effort. The OP has to traverse the resulting array in any event. It's no overhead at all to build the logic of missing results into the loop, and it's infinitely more scalable and flexible (it can be even be done client side, in javascript)

Comment: @Strawberry the OP is searching for a "obvious, elegant way of doing it" and likes "to get SQL to do as much as possible". I have a very similar construct to fill empty dates in a chart provider Laravel application that SQL serves in mere miliseconds, php took about 300ms for the same job (more depending on how large the date range is). Additionally, if set up in a view you just query that. Nothing more scalable, flexible or performant than that - at least that was my impression with the solution I had.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos that works - thankyou very much!