# mysql select months for 3 years including those with no values

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: months and starter

```
mysql > select * from months
---------------------
| id   | month      |
| ---- | ---------- |
| 1    | 2012-01-31 |
| 2    | 2012-02-29 |
| 3    | 2012-03-31 |
| 4    | 2012-04-30 |
| 5    | 2012-05-31 |
| 6    | 2012-06-30 |
| 7    | 2012-07-31 |
| 8    | 2012-08-31 |
| 9    | 2012-09-30 |
| 10   | 2012-10-31 |
| 11   | 2012-11-30 |
| 12   | 2012-12-31 |
---------------------
```

Query from the table `starter` returns

```
+----------+------------+
|       id | startdate  |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | 2017-07-20 |
|        2 | 2017-07-19 |
|        4 | 2017-07-01 |
|        5 | 2017-06-28 |
|        6 | 2017-05-04 |
|        7 | 2017-04-03 |
|        8 | 2017-01-09 |
|        9 | 2017-02-01 |
|       10 | 2016-01-01 |
|       11 | 2015-01-07 |
|       12 | 2015-01-19 |
|       13 | 2016-02-09 |
+----------+------------+
```

I modified https://stackoverflow.com/a/17916395/8104587 to this:

```
SELECT concat(date_format(m.month,'%b'),' ',year(CURRENT_DATE())) as Months, 
COUNT(s.id) AS Total FROM months AS m LEFT JOIN starter s ON 
MONTH(m.month) = MONTH(s.startdate) AND YEAR(s.startdate) = 
YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) GROUP BY m.month
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------+
| Months   | Total |
+----------+-------+
| Jan 2017 |     1 |
| Feb 2017 |     1 |
| Mar 2017 |     0 |
| Apr 2017 |     1 |
| May 2017 |     1 |
| Jun 2017 |     1 |
| Jul 2017 |     3 |
| Aug 2017 |     0 |
| Sep 2017 |     0 |
| Oct 2017 |     0 |
| Nov 2017 |     0 |
| Dec 2017 |     0 |
+----------+-------+
```

I want to be able to generate for 3 years from `2015` to `2017` in this order

```
+----------+-------+
| Months   | Total |
+----------+-------+
| Jan 2017 |     1 |
| Jan 2016 |     1 |
| Jan 2015 |     0 |
| Feb 2017 |     1 |
| Feb 2016 |     1 |
| Feb 2015 |     0 |
...
| Dec 2017 |     0 |
| Dec 2016 |     0 |
| Dec 2015 |     0 |
+----------+-------+
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Create another table with the years, then join to it and generate the dates by splitting the year, month, day and using the year from the new table, and the month, day from the existing table.

Comment: Instead, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You can get a counting table for year and month as following:

```
SET @mn = 1; SET @r = 2015;
SELECT @mn, FLOOR(@yr / 12), CASE
    WHEN @mn = 12 THEN @mn := 1
    WHEN @mn < 12 THEN @mn := @mn + 1 
END,
@yr := @yr + 1 FROM anything WHERE @yr < (2018 * 12)
```

This you can `LEFT JOIN` to your data table and get a list of all years and months. Maybe there are more elegant `SELECT`-statements to achieve the same, but at least it works. `anything` is just any table that you have as placeholder for the `SELECT` statement. For speed it should be a small one.

Comment: When I run this query against the `months` table, it returns empty set. `mysql> SELECT @mn, FLOOR(@yr / 12), CASE
    ->     WHEN @mn = 12 THEN @mn := 1
    ->     WHEN @mn < 12 THEN @mn := @mn + 1
    -> END,
    -> @yr := @yr + 1 FROM months WHERE @yr < (2018 * 12)
    -> ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)`