# How to add month name with 0 total if data not exist in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch data of the user's from `created_date` to till current data by month name and year with each month's total price.

**Try 1:**

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(start_time) month, YEAR(start_time) year, SUM(price) total
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.id= 33
GROUP BY YEAR(start_time), MONTH(start_time);
```

Output:

```
month           year    total
July            2019    360
September       2019    2160
October         2019    360
```

Expected output:

```
All month name and total will be 0 if data not exist. 

month           year    total
Jan             2018    0
Feb             2018    0
...
Dec             2018    0
Jan             2019    0
Feb             2019    0
Mar             2019    0
Apr             2019    0
May             2019    0
Jun             2019    0
July            2019    360
Aug             2019    0
Sep             2019    2160
Oct             2019    360
Nov             2019    0
Dec             2019    0
```

After some RND I found one way and I have also tried that but now works.

**Try 2:**

```
 SELECT IFNULL(SUM(ri.price),0) AS total, m.month
 FROM (
       SELECT 'Jan' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Feb' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Mar' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Apr' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'May' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Jun' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Jul' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Aug' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Sep' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Oct' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Nov' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Dec' AS MONTH
      ) AS m
LEFT JOIN table_u pu 
ON MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(pu.created_date, '2019'),'%M %Y')) = MONTH(pu.created_date)
AND YEAR(pu.created_date) = '2019'
LEFT JOIN table ri 
ON ri.id = pu.id
GROUP BY m.month
ORDER by 1+1;
```

Here is my [refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17916567/8612835) link.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep using `LEFT JOIN` (but only once) with a integer generator upto 12 (instead of month names, also easy using within the `ORDER BY` clause ), since you are able to get the month names by `monthname()` function. From your second query, I considered the current year. So, use :

```
SET @year=YEAR(NOW());

SELECT 
      MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(concat(YEAR(NOW()),',',m.month,',1'),"%Y,%m,%d")) as month,
      @year as year , SUM( COALESCE( pu.price, 0) ) as total
  FROM (
        SELECT rn as month 
          FROM
          (
           SELECT @rn := if(@i = @rn, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
                  @i := @i+1
             FROM information_schema.character_sets
             JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @rn := 0) as q_iter
            LIMIT 12
          ) q
        ) AS m
   LEFT JOIN table_u pu ON MONTH(pu.start_time) = m.month
    AND YEAR(pu.start_time) = @year
    AND ID = 33
  GROUP BY m.month
  ORDER by m.month;
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=343ef1db7b997cffbf96b89ad5bb6536)</kbd>

**Edit** ( *From the beginning of the year 2018 to the end of the current year* ) :

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(
         STR_TO_DATE(
           CONCAT(m.year,',',if(mod(m.month,12)=0,12,mod(m.month,12)),',1'),"%Y,%m,%d")
           ) 
       as month, 
       year, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN YEAR(pu.start_time) = m.year AND MONTH(pu.start_time) = m.month
                 THEN 
                      COALESCE( pu.price, 0) 
                 ELSE
                      0
            END ) as total 
  FROM
  (
       SELECT @i := if( @i = 12 , 1 , @i+1) as month,
              @j := @j + 1,    
              @k:= if( @i = 1 and @j > 12, @k - 1, @k ) as year
             FROM information_schema.character_sets
         JOIN (SELECT @i := 0, @j := 0, @k:=YEAR(now())) as q_iter
   ) m
   LEFT JOIN table_u pu ON MONTH(pu.start_time) = m.month    
    AND ID = 33
  GROUP BY month, year
 HAVING year >= ( SELECT MIN( YEAR(start_time) ) FROM table_u  )
  ORDER BY year, m.month;
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8c37ecc2957ec7a5f82562f4e87fffa8)</kbd>

Comment: Ok, I'll try in a while and let you know.

Comment: I have checked and this works fine for the current year. I just need one more level up. For example, I have a date `2018-10-10` Then I need data from that 2010's month to current month.

Comment: By the way, this query looks awesome. I have never imagined that I could run this type of query. Maybe it may take some time to understand how this works. :)

Comment: This works me. And thanks for this awesome answer. :)

Comment: This query is all most correct and also in same format which I want. After test your query I found that it sums correctly in the year of 2019 but not in 2018. Can you please tell me where I have to look. I didn't get much idea in this query.

Comment: Hi @SachinShah. I was feeling tired last night. Let me check in the day again. Now it's about 4 AM here :) See you.

Comment: OK I fixed @SachinShah .

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros Özhan. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: @SachinShah did you look at the demo2 ..?

Comment: Let me try again.

Comment: Yes I looked into demo 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200911/discussion-between-barbaros-ozhan-and-sachin-shah).

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in your table for *all* months, but just not for that `id`, then you can switch to conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(start_time) as month, YEAR(start_time) as year, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.id = 33 THEN price ELSE 0 END) as total
FROM table t1
GROUP BY YEAR(start_time),MONTHNAME(start_time)
ORDER BY MIN(start_time);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case it's not possible that I have a month name for particular user in year. For example, He didn't work for 3 months then I need show him 0 for respective months.

Comment: @SachinShah . . . You are missing the point (and didn't run the query obviously).  If you have the months in the data for *any* id, then the month will be in the result set using this query.  The data is only for `33`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating nonexistent year-month pairs by using user variables:

```
SELECT monthname(str_to_date(concat_ws(',',ym.month,'01,01'),'%m,%d,%y')) month
     , ym.year year 
     , sum(price)
  FROM table1 t1
    RIGHT JOIN( SELECT @year  := if(@month=12, @year+1, @year   ) year
                    , @month := if(@month=12, 1      , @month+1) month
                 FROM table1
                    , ( SELECT @startYear := min(start_time)
                             , @endYear   := year(now())
                             , @month := 12
                             , @year  := min(start_time)-1
                          FROM table1
                      ) t
                 WHERE (@year,@month) < (@endYear,12)
             ) ym
      ON    ym.year  = year(t1.start_time)
        AND ym.month = month(t1.start_time)
  GROUP BY year(t1.start_time)
         , month(t1.start_time)
```

The `ym` derived table is to provide year-month pairs starting on min year in table1 upto current year.
The innermost SELECT is for variables initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It doesn't work for me. I got this output. 
month      year      sum(price)
January   NULL    360
January   NULL    2160
January   NULL    360

Can you please check my expected output. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT to_char(start_time,'month')MONTH,to_char(start_time,'yyyy')YEAR,SUM(price)total 
FROM   TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY to_char(start_time,'month'),to_char(start_time,'yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: `to_char` is the default function ?

Comment: Yes ! to_char is the default function. use for date will be converted to a string. for more information please refer below link. [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Comment: Okay I'll try again and let you know.

Comment: `FUNCTION TO_CHAR does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the correct output which I want.

```
select
DATE_FORMAT(m1, '%M - %Y')

from
(
  select
  ('2013-07-23')
  +INTERVAL m MONTH as m1
  from
  (
     select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as m from
     (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t1,
     (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t2,
     (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t3,
     (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) t4,
     (select @rownum:=-1) t0
  ) d1
) d2
  where m1<=NOW()
  order by m1
```